# How to force a Float to display with full precision w/o scientific notation and not as a string?

Tags: ruby, floating-point

How do you force a float to display with all significant places / full precision without scientific notation in Ruby?

Presently I convert a BigDecimal to Float, `BigDecimal(0.000000001453).to_f`, however this yields a resultant float of 1.453e-09.  If I do something like `"%14.12f" % BigDecimal("0.000000001453").to_f` I get a string.  In this case, however, a string as output is unacceptable as I need it as an actual numeric float without scientific notation.

--- Edit---

Alright, let me give some context here, which will probably require a change of my original question.

I'm attempting to create a graph with Highstock & lazy_high_chart.  Earlier today I was able to draw graphs just fine when the floats were emitting to the resultant js as full precision floats vs showing up in scientific notation.  Hence I felt that the problem resides in this issue.

But after the few inputs I'm getting here, perhaps I need some further review of the source and my assumption is misplaced.  I'll let you decide:

```
@h = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
  hours_of_readings = 1
  reading_intervals = 1 #hour
  readings_per_hour = 60

  readings = ModelName.order("date DESC").select('data_readings.data2, data_readings.data1, data_readings.date').limit(hours_of_readings * readings_per_hour).all

  data1_and_date_series = Array.new
  data2_and_date_series = Array.new
  dates = Array.new

  # I have been thinking that the problem lies here in the "row.data1.to_f" and
  #   "row.data2.to_f" and thus this is the root of my initial question in terms 
  #   of it emitting scientific notation to the js output in the format of:
  #   [[1.0e-09], [1.04e-09],[9.4e-09], ... [3.68e-09]]
  data1_and_date_series = readings.map{|row| [(row.date.to_i * 1000), (row.data1.to_f if BigDecimal(row.data1) != BigDecimal("-1000.0"))] }
  data2_and_date_series = readings.map{|row| [(row.date.to_i * 1000), (row.data2.to_f if BigDecimal(row.data2) != BigDecimal("-1000.0"))] }


  f.series(
      :name => 'Data1',
      :data => data1_and_date_series,
      :pointStart => Time.now.to_i * 1000,
      :pointEnd => hours_of_readings.hours.ago.to_i * 1000,
      :pointInterval => reading_intervals.hour * 1000,
      :color => 'blue'
  )
  f.series(
      :name => 'Data2)',
      :data => data2_and_date_series,
      :pointStart => Time.now.to_i * 1000,
      :pointEnd => hours_of_readings.hours.ago.to_i * 1000,
      :pointInterval => reading_intervals.hour.to_i * 1000,
      :color => 'red'
  )

  f.chart({:defaultSeriesType=>"spline" })
  f.yAxis [
        {:title => { :text => "Label 1", :margin => 10} },
        {:title => { :text => "Label 2 (groups)"}, :opposite => true},
        {:max => 0},
        {:min => -0.000000001}
  ]
  f.options[:xAxis] = {
      :title => { :text => "Time"},
      :type => "datetime"
  }
  f.title(:text => "Title")
  f.legend(:align => 'right', :verticalAlign => 'top', :y => 75, :x => -50, :layout => 'vertical') # override the default values
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? You seem have both of the formats you need already: The `1.453e-09` notation is just for display, internally it is stored as a numeric float value, so you can do math with it in that form. If you are going to display it, the string you get from the `"%14.12f"` formatting operation should work fine.

Comment: When I emit this (in this case with lazy_high_charts) I end up with scientific notation within the resultant json.  From everything I've seen and tried previous to this, the result needs to be a float or integer.  Frankly earlier today I had the floats coming out w/o scientific notation and from between then and now something changed in my logic while working with the datetime stamps and now it's back to emitting scientific notation which is not showing in the graph.  At this point the only thing I can see that's a differential is this formatting issue at the js output level.

Comment: Javascript understands scientific notation: http://jsfiddle.net/SJFTe/ can you leave it in your output?

Comment: Note that neither of the lines `... = Array.new` seems necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string representation and the actual value of a float are two different things.

What you see on screen/print-out is always a string representation, be it in scientific notation or "normal" notation. A float is converted to its string representation by `to_s`, `puts`, `"%.10f" %` and others.

The float value itself is independent of that. So your last sentence does not make much sense. The output is always a string.

To enforce a certain float format in Rails' `to_json` you can overwrite `Float#encode_json`, e.g.

```
class ::Float
  def encode_json(opts = nil)
    "%.10f" % self
  end
end
```

Put this before your code above. Note that -- depending on your actual values -- you might need more sophisticated logic to produce reasonable strings.

Comment: Right and that was the purpose of my last statement, I'm trying to coerce the float to emit as a full precision float to a json / js result vs appearing as a scientific notation number.  You may refer to my comment to @ctcherry above.

Comment: There you go, edited the question with code to give you context... probably changed the nature of the question, but at least you can understand the big picture now.

Comment: @ylluminate This looks like a direct solution to what you were originally asking. Does using this solve your issue?

Comment: I did place this in the model and it doesn't seem to really accomplish the goal, no.  From what I'm seeing I don't believe that this library is using `encode_json` to emit the results to js. Hmm.

Comment: @ylluminate: I'm quite sure it does. One problem might be that the code I suggested has to be outside of any class definition. I updated the answer to address this issue (`::Float` instead of `Float`).

Comment: Your change did effect the output, yes.  So that modification was useful, however it is now emitting them as strings.

Comment: Okay, so that approximately answered the original question and was certainly useful to know so I'm going to mark it as the answer, but I've tried to express a little more of what I've learned in this new question: [How do you modify array mapping data structure resultant from Ruby map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814902/how-do-you-modify-array-mapping-data-structure-resultant-from-ruby-map)

Comment: It's important to be aware this patches the `Float` class itself and will affect JSON encoding for the whole application.  It doesn't matter whether you put it in a specific model file.  Also, while using regular fractions instead of scientific notation is harmless, the specific `"%.10f"` format *will* reduce precision of small floats.  E.g. `"%.10f" % 1e-20 == "0.0000000000"`.

Comment: @Beni Cherniavsky-Paskin: Very true. Could you please edit it in into my answer?

Answer (score 4):

Will this work for you -

```
>> 0.000000001453
=> 1.453e-09 # what you are getting right now
>> puts "%1.12f" % 0.000000001453
0.000000001453 # what you need
=> nil
```

Comment: As per my earlier remark in the initial message, I was aiming towards getting a float output vs string; that can be changed back with a to_f, but I still see it in scientific notation.  I've gone ahead and provided the full code of the section to give you some context now. Even though it probably changed the nature of the initial question, I figure it's better to give you a full snapshot into what's going on.